# Remove the duplicates based on the condition in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
ID     STATUS
1      Active
1      Completed
2      Active
3      Completed
4      Completed
4      Active
```

From the above I would like to remove duplicate ID and keep the Status with Active.

Expected Output:

```
ID     STATUS
1      Active
2      Active
3      Completed
4      Active
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is filter groups with no `Active` by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) with mask by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for non equal and chain with inverted mask by `~`:

```
m = df['STATUS'].ne('Active')

df = df[m.groupby(df['ID']).transform('all') | ~m]
print (df)
   ID     STATUS
0   1     Active
2   2     Active
3   3  Completed
5   4     Active
```

Another idea is convert all `STATUS` to ordered `Categorical`s, so if sorting and remove duplciates get `Active` if exist else another values by priority with position of values of list `c`:

```
c = ['Active','Completed']
df['STATUS'] = pd.Categorical(df['STATUS'], ordered=True, categories=c)

df = df.sort_values(['ID','STATUS']).drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])
print (df)
   ID     STATUS
0   1     Active
2   2     Active
3   3  Completed
5   4     Active
```